# AngularJS Material not displayed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to learn how to use AngularJS and AngularJS Material using following codes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>

    <script>
    angular.module('F1FeederApp', [ 'ngMaterial' ]).controller('driversController',
            function($scope) {
            }).config(
            function($mdThemingProvider) {
                $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('pink')
                        .accentPalette('orange');
            });
    ;
    </script>

    <!-- default themes and core styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
</head>
    <body ng-app="F1FeederApp">
        <md-content>
            <md-toolbar class="md-tall md-accent">
              <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <span>Toolbar: tall (md-accent)</span>
              </h2>
            </md-toolbar>

            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </md-content>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the Material is not displayed. What could be wrong with my code?

Console in Browser doesn't give me any error.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code and it works fine on Chrome, FireFox, and Safari.

[image]

By the way, you have an extra ; before your closing script tag

```
<script>
angular.module('F1FeederApp', [ 'ngMaterial' ]).controller('driversController',
        function($scope) {
        }).config(
        function($mdThemingProvider) {
            $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('pink')
                    .accentPalette('orange');
        });
;
</script>
```

I recommend you to check your angular and angular material versions,
or check if there is a problem in your .js files.

Comment: The extra semicolon should be not the problem. However I can try to create new project and it works.